# Is there a way to disable the "keyboard-dismiss" button?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to disable/hide this keyboard-dismiss button and keep the soft-keyboard open?

I want to have the default back-button there and when that button is pressed it should `finish()` my activity without having to dismiss the keyboard first.

[image: Nexus 5 rocks!]


I have tried this: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"` in my manifest file, but that didn't do what I expected.

Comment: Why would you want to disturb your users by making your app work differently from other apps?

Comment: I have a lockscreen; I would like to keep the keyboard open or dismiss the whole activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided that I shouldn't mess with the Android standard meaning and I have chosen to let the users dismiss the keyboard if they wish to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your activity in manifest file. This will work.

Comment: Nope, it hides the keyboard on activity startup, that's why I have `stateAlwaysVisible`

Comment: i got your problem use setOnEditorActionListener for your edittext to finish your activity  refer this url http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener)